# Draggable After to Be Dropped From Another Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm implementing a solution to drag an element from a container to another. Until here it's ok.
The problem is that after to be dropped in the second container, the element is non anymore draggable inside the same container.

```
$(".draggableExtra").draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone"
});

$(".body").droppable({
        accept: '.draggableExtra',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.remove();
            ui.helper.clone(true).prependTo(extra.parent());
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in JQuery 1.5, where there is a bug about the cloned draggable elements.
On JQuery 1.4.4 works fine, but instead to use an older version of jquery I solved using an hidden element in the second container that I will move when I finish to drag the element from the first container.